# Selecting rows with specific values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
print(df)

  id  num1   num2   num3  num4  num5  num6  
  a   43      25    37     8    36    20  
  b   43      36    19     25   44    15  
  c   43      25    23     38   1     8
```

How do I select all the rows that have the values 8 and 25 in them and create a new dataframe for just those rows?.The dataframe has thousands of rows and the values could be in any column.

Comment: `df[(df == 8) | (df == 25)]`

Comment: @iDrwish This creates a dataframe containing all the rows with everything set to Nan except for values 8 and 25.

Comment: Whats with the downvotes i just dont get it

Comment: I can't say for sure, but If I had to guess, you didn't provide the data output needed, and the question can be easily understood the way I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a boolean check for each of the values in each row and then slice the dataframe.  Here is an example that requires the row to have BOTH 8 and 25.  If you want any row that has 8 or 25, use `|` instead of `&`

```
ix = df.eq(8).any(axis=1) & df.eq(25).any(axis=1)
df2 = df[ix]
```